# Maximum area of quadrilateral with sides and diagonals not exceeding a given value

Tags: calculus, geometry, area, quadrilateral

What is the maximum area of quadrilateral such that max|sides, diagonals|< x ?

I know that the maximum area would be the square area of diagonals of length $x$ 
 which has area $x^2/2$, but how to prove that?

Comment: do you mean the lengths of all sides and diagonals are less than x ?

Comment: yes , i only need to prove how the square gives maximum area

Comment: It the answer solves your homework, please consider click the accept bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the two diagonals be  $l, m\le x$ with angle $\alpha$. Then
$$
Area = \frac{1}{2}lm\sin \alpha \le \frac{1}{2}x^2
$$

Comment: how did you get the 0.5 lm  sin (alpha

Comment: @IkramIbrahim The area of the quadrilateral, either convex or concave, is exactly $\frac{lm\sin \alpha}{2}$. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral#Area_of_a_convex_quadrilateral